# JavaScript LocalScope variable is not able to access in console

Tags: javascript

I am able to see the value of variable on mouse hover and in right panel Scope tab, But I am not able to access in developer console. Also it is not in closure scope. Please see attached snap.

[image]

Comment: Does your project use a module bundler like Webpack or Parcel?

Comment: @NickParsons but when we have debug point in that function as shown in image then it should able to access in developer tool console because we are in the scope of that function.

Comment: @Marian13 no we are not using.